# Migrating from Aspdnsf to aspdnsf multi-store

Tags: aspdotnetstorefront

I worked on an existing project that is using aspdotnetstorefront and dotnetnuke in VS 2008. Now, the company decided to upgrade the project to VS 2012 and make it a Multi-Store application. I am a newbie and dont know much about aspdotnetstorefront. Can some body point me as to where I can get more Documentation/Support Groups/Links to get more information please? So far, I came across this link, http://manual.aspdotnetstorefront.com/c-79-multistore.aspx

Thanks!!

Comment: I edited your TBBT Q on TV&M to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More importantly than the VS version is the ASPDNSF version.  If you are going from < 9 there is more work involved in getting rid of the Component Art Menu and other skin changes due to the change to master templates. Also in the current version (v9.4.1) there is more skin work as they default skins are now responsive (YEAH!).

This link covers most of what you need to know at a basic level: http://manual.aspdotnetstorefront.com/p-948-upgrading-to-a-9x-version.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. Our current version is 7.2. We will be upgrading it and making it a Multi-Store.

Answer (score 0):

What version of ASPDNSF are you currently using? The move to Multi Store is not much difference unless you are upgrading to a newer version.

If its above version 9.1.0.1 then ML (your current version) and Multi Store were merged.

There is also a dedicated support forum here https://forums.vortx.com/

Comment: Thanks, the current version is 7.2, and will be upgrading it to the latest version.

Comment: Ok in that case there is quite a change in the coding. Best thing is to ensure that all the functionality is working then work on the skinning after.